# Como Criar Dados Tabulados com Link Ver Mais?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou puxando da base de dados registros de uma determinada tabela.

Quero mostrar apenas de 4 em 4 registros na tela. Mas gostaria de puxar todos de uma vez ao invés de fazer paginação (1, 2, 3, 4).

Quero mostrar 4 linhas e colocar embaixo um botão **VER MAIS** e quando o usuário clicasse mostrasse mais 4 linhas e assim por diante até acabar.

Como posso começar a fazer isso ?

Não tenho nada pronto. Apenas a tabela, mas diferenciada.

Não fiz a tabela com `table` e sim com `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido.

Fiz um **CSS** e um pouco de **jQuery**.

### CSS

```
ul {
   li {
      &:nth-child(n+5){
      display: none;
   }
}
```

No código acima eu mostro apenas 4 linhas.

### HTML

```
<div class="btn-ver-mais">
   <span>Ver mais</span>
</div>
```

Acima o botão de **Ver mais**.

### jQuery

```
// Limitação de Lista de Concessionárias de 4 em 4 linhas
$('.btn-ver-mais').click(function() {
    $('.content-resultados li:hidden').slice(0, 4).show();
    if ($('.content-resultados li').length == $('.content-resultados li:visible').length) {
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

E no código acima quando clico no botão **Ver mais**, seleciono todas as linhas que estão escondidas ou `hidden`, a partir da posição 0 e mostro até 4 linhas, com a função `slide()`;

E se o número de linhas visível for igual ao total de linhas desabilito o botão **Ver mais**.

Obrigado pra quem votou no fechar por não estar suficientemente clara.